# What difference between "Clear text communication not permitted" problem's solutions

Tags: android, android-networking

We know that Android Pie doesn't allow Clear text communication. And I found two solutions. All of them work fine. But what is the difference between them? Thanks.

**Solution 1:**

Manifest:

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

**Solution 2:**

`@xml/network_security_config.xml`

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Manifest:

`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And I found for me two solutions

Neither are the correct solution: use HTTPS. I expect that Google will increasingly penalize apps that use the solutions that you cite, possibly including a future ban from the Play Store.

> But what difference between them?

They have the same effect. Network security configuration (your second solution) is far more powerful and flexible. `android:usesCleartextTraffic` will be ignored on Android 7.0+ if you use network security configuration for anything.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you expect Google's penalties/bans for these solutions? These two solutions are usually the recommended ones on SO. I think I saw something similar on google's developer page. The second approach is also recommended by some bigger companies, for example twitter's moPub, has an: add a network security configuration file in their documents. I just started playing with Android pie, so I might be missing something. Thanks

Comment: @Banana: The second one isn't "add[ing] a network security configuration". It is enabling all cleartext traffic. It happens to abuse network security configuration to accomplish it. I expect Google to punish Android developers much along the same lines as how Google punishes Web developers. For example, sometime this year IIRC, Chrome will start reporting plain HTTP sites as broken.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I don't think it is clear in the official google docs. I believe that companies like the moPub (I mentioned before) will have to update their documentation as well.